# Rellenar un arreglo aleatoriamente C++/POO

Tags: c++, array, poo, random

Este programa trata sobre una carrera de personas
Lo que pasa es que tengo un arreglo de int, y necesito llenarlo con números al azar, pero que no se repitan.

Por ejemplo, si la cantidad en el arreglo es 5, ocupo que me genere números al azar del 1 al 5 pero que no se repitan. Algo así

```
|2|4|1|5|3| ← Que se generen aleatoriamente cada vez que se ejecuta.
```

Cantidad=10

```
|8|2|3|6|9|5|4|1|10|7|
```

Comment: Yo rellenaría el array con los números ordenados y, en una segunda pasada, desordenaría el array calculando N veces dos posiciones aleatorias que intercambiasen sus valores

Answer (score 2):

La estrategia habitual para lo que necesitas es generar los números en orden y después desordenarlos. Para desordenarlos dispones de la función [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) de la cabecera [`<algoritmh>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm).

Ten en cuenta que esta utilidad tiene varias versiones que están deprecadas, la adecuada es:

```
template< class RandomIt, class URBG >
void shuffle( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, URBG&& g );
```

Los dos primeros parámetros son los iteradores de inicio y final de la secuencia que se quiere mezclar y el último parámetro es un generador de números aleatorios. Estos generadores están disponibles a través de la cabecera [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random).

Sabiendo todo lo anterior, la estrategia a seguir sería esta:

```
// Generamos números de '1' a 'cantidad' dentro de un vector:
std::vector<int> numeros(cantidad);
std::generate(numeros.begin(), numeros.end(), [n = 0] () mutable { return ++n; });

// Creamos un dispositivo y generador de números aleatorios.
std::random_device dispositivo;
std::mt19937 generador(dispositivo());
// Mezclamos los números generados.
std::shuffle(numeros.begin(), numeros.end(), generador);
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVDNbsIwDD6Tp7CYNFKxIRCHibbrZY8xTVNITInUOlXi9IJ49q5dWwan3eLP35@jm@ZVV4rKrnuypKtoEHLrAntUdSH@MFWVzls@P4BekXEPSIuanS@EsMRQK0syERexGCatiK1RJhOLwCZNtYsMeQ7Lj2mRwvK2swRFcSeZ8NE@7@0KoFijd0HOpGQWl0joFaOcGJsjlkORl1myQTLD@EnwDtsvkAnUkdWxQriAR46eYL2mDK7JLXk89dtgazWCsaFxwbJt3Zxa8@5w2L/BmG6cl3ckmfROMBLDOZ5O1f/tbka/JU7Og9SOAoOK7OB5ZEM6yxKxePzXidC/VrAaLKbLtpm4dt1uK34A)</kbd>.

Comment: Y en caso de querer usar un `random_shuffle` para revolver los números de una columna en una matriz, cómo podría hacerlo?
Por ejemplo, si tengo una matriz:

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

Revolver una columna:

4 2 3
7 5 6
1 8 9

Comment: Le pasas a la función el inicio y el final del rango que quieras desordenar.